# R ggplot2: Unable to change y axis limits (zero_range error)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Plotting a bar chart with error bars in `ggplot2`, but when I try to change the y-axis limits, I am thrown a strange error:

```
mydata <- data.frame(set=c("a","b","c","d"), 
                     percent=c(5,1,2.5,8), 
                     lower=c(3.5,.7,2.3,7.1), 
                     upper=c(6.5,1.7,2.7,8.9))

ggplot(mydata, aes(set, percent)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=upper, ymin=lower),
                  width=0.5, position=position_dodge(0.9)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(seq(0, 12, 3)))
```

This yields `Error in zero_range(range) : x must be length 1 or 2`. However, if I use `scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,12))` instead, there is no error, but the limits extend to 12.5 in 0.5 increments.

Any idea what is causing this? I've not seen "zero_range" before.

Comment: @dww I think what we're seeing is actually the documented and intended behavior of both the `breaks` and the `limits` arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `breaks` argument:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 12), breaks=seq(0, 12, 3))
```

[image: plot]